# Integrate Stripe 3d secure on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I´ve been working with stripe payment and now I want integrate 3d secure but documentation doesn't help me, Has anyone worked with 3d secure on ios?

My main question is how or when init the STPPaymentHandler that provide the STPThreeDSUI to handle authentication.

please help.

this links doesn´t have useful information

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#ios-testing

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of how to use the STPPaymentHandler here: https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/client/ios/App%20(Swift)/CheckoutViewController.swift#L112

Essentially, after the customer has submitted their payment details you want to get the globally shared instance of the [STPPaymentHandler](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#submit-payment) (using `STPPaymentHandler.shared()`). You can then call the `confirmPayment` method to handle any needed authentication.

I'd suggest taking a look at Stripe's [guide for accepting a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#submit-payment) which touches on this. If you're using the prebuilt UI you use this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#submit-payment) instead